# Finding last active time for logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am using ruby on rails session to store a user cookie to keep them logged in, so I can't just update a last_seen column after they login.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to find out if a user has been active in the last day.  This is what I have so far but I'm wondering if there's a better way:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :update_last_seen

private
  def update_last_seen
    if (DateTime.now - 1.day) < current_user.last_seen
      current_user.last_seen = DateTime.now
      current_user.save
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that it is going to get called with every request.  Is there any way to avoid this?  Does the session cookie get updated somehow when a user is active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is exactly how you should go about it.  `before_filter`s are a great way to keep track of things like that, and are how `authlogic` implements it's authentication system as well.  There's no way to do processing on one request "per day".  If you use [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) as your authentication method, it has last-login time built in.  You can see an example of it [here](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example).

Comment: Ok thanks, it looks like update_last_request_at! might be the method Authlogic uses: http://github.com/qoobaa/sms/blob/41e2ee0ea1425b44db29150a940f153aaaac50d7/vendor/gems/authlogic-1.4.1/lib/authlogic/session/timeout.rb.